Python- unexpected result in a nested for loop
I am getting unexpected results from a simple python function that uses a nested for loop. csv_file_a has 28257 rows and csv_file_b has 6822 rows.
I was expecting that if I increment the counter in the inner for loop, the counter will be 28257 * 6822 but that doesn't seem to be occurring. If I increment the counter in the outer for loop, I get 28257 (as expected) but when I increment the counter in the inner for loop, I get 6822. What could be the problem here?
def compare_data(csv_file_a, csv_file_b):
    fp_a = open(csv_file_a, mode="r", newline='')
    _sx = csv.reader(fp_a)
    fp_b = open(csv_file_b, mode="r", newline='')
    y = csv.reader(fp_b)
    counter = 0
    for _x in _sx:
        counter += 1   #I get an output of 28257 - number of rows in csv_file_a
        for _item in y:
            #counter += 1  #I get an output of 6822 - number of rows in csv_file_b
            if somecondition:
                print(something)
            else:
                print(something else)
    print(counter)
 
compare_data(csv_file_a, csv_file_b)


Since we can't run the code, have to guess. So here's my guess :-)
After the first time
        for _item in y:

completes, y is exhausted, and so every later time you try to execute that for loop, it doesn't do anything. So counter is only incremented the first time that loop is encountered, so counter is left with the number of elements it got from y (all of which it got during the first time that loop was executed).
To get what you wanted, read all of y into, say, a list before the first loop is executed. A list can be iterated over any number of times. Anything named "reader()" probably delivers its result sequence only once, and can't be usefully restarted "by magic". You'll have to, say, read it into a list (already suggested), or call something appropriate to ask it to reset itself (e.g., for files, call its .seek(0) method).

Thank you Tim, makes sense.
"Anything named "reader()" probably delivers its result sequence only once, and can't be usefully restarted "by magic"."

import csv

def compare_data(csv_file_a, csv_file_b):
with open(csv_file_a, mode="r", newline='') as fp_a:
    _sx = csv.reader(fp_a)
    with open(csv_file_b, mode="r", newline='') as fp_b:
        y = csv.reader(fp_b)
        counter = 0
        for _x in _sx:
            counter += 1   # Increment for each row in csv_file_a
            fp_b.seek(0)  # Reset the file cursor to the beginning of 
   csv_file_b
            for _item in y:
                #counter += 1  # Increment for each row in csv_file_b
                if somecondition:
                    print(something)
                else:
                    print(something else)
        print(counter)

   compare_data(csv_file_a, csv_file_b)


A code-only answer is not high quality. While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.
